# Wifi and Ethernet Problem

Tags: wireless, network-manager

I have two problems.

1. I connect my computer to a network using wi-fi but when my computer comes back from sleep I get a message that wi-fi network disconnected.
2. Network manager says "Ethernet Network() : device not managed"
   I've Ubuntu 16.04 lts installed

Comment: Please ask one question at a time.

Comment: If you want your WiFi to restart after when waking from sleep then remove `2.` from your question.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! **;-)** We're sorry but Ask Ubuntu is not a forum but a Question&Answer site: It works best if you ask *one question*, so you can receive *one answer*.  When you ask multiple questions, you need to find one expert versed in multiple areas which becomes more unlikely the more questions you put into... well, one question!  **;-)** So please, split up your question into multiple questions...

Answer (score 0):

I have had similar problems with my wifi. It was due to my interfaces file being manually configured since I was building my own system from a basic install with no desktop. Because I didn't like the Unity desktop and didn't want to go through the hassle of UN-installing and installing a new desktop and what not. Once I found a desktop I liked my wifi wasn't being managed because the system was reading the interfaces file to configure the network once I removed my manual configurations the system started using the network manager.

edit the interfaces file by typing: sudo nano /etc/network/interfaces

Then either comment out any manual configurations for wifi. my file looks like this:

## This file describes the network interfaces available on your system

## and how to activate them. For more information, see interfaces(5).

## The loopback network interface

auto lo
iface lo inet loopback